# Rails Rendering partial with form object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to render a partial 'colordata' after selecting a :color from the drop down list as it involves Ajax. I am not able to observe any change in main page. Even form is undefined in colordata partial.

Here's my schema of model Order

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "design"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "color"
    t.string "lotnumber"
    t.float "consumption", limit: 24
    t.string "number"
  end
```

Here's the ajax call

```
  $("select[name='order[color]']").change(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url: "colordata",
       type: "post",
       data:{
         "color": $(this).val()
       },
       dataType: JSON,
       success: function(data){
       }
     });
   });
```

Here's the controller.

```
def colordata
    request.POST.each do |key, value|
      @color = value
    end
    @lotdetail= Master::Yarn.where('color like?', @color)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here's the Colordata.js.erb

```
$(".lot").innerHTML += "<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'colordata'),locals: {form: form) %>"
```

Here's the partial _colordata.html.erb

```
<%= form.label :lotnumber %>
<%= form.collection_select(:lotnumber, @lotdetail, @lotdetail.lotnumber,@lotdetail.lotnumber,prompt: "Select the Yarn")%>
```

errors are

1. form is not define in _colordata.html.erb
2. Partial is not appending into the class lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To append your partial with jquery, you can use the `append` method instead. `locals` should be define inside the render.
So you can fix like that :

```
$(".lot").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'colordata', locals: { form: form })) %>")
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff1949dd9c8>:0x00007ff194ea0e10>
Did you mean?  fork):
     $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
       $(".lot").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'colordata',locals: {form: form})) %>")
   )};

Comment: @AmitojSingh It's because the `form` variable is define nowhere inside your js.erb file (that i was assuming it was). You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693756/9541423) for this issue

Comment: It works using fields_for tag in partial But append is still not working.