# More than a simple nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**campaign.rb**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

Campaign has 2 attributes: title and description
Item has 1 attirubte: name

I'll try explain myself by words, I want to create a nested form where they user insert the campaign's name and description but he can insert more than just 1 item, he can insert a list of items (in particular there will be a "+" button that when clicked a new item row will appear and the user can insert items).

At the end all is send all together clicking just one submit button.
How can I reach my goal with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a question just yesterday. Here's the link: [Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for with f.fields_for and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436526/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-f-fields-for-and-ajax/20441143?noredirect=1#comment30551890_20441143)

I'll write out how it works & provide some resources to help give you some more ideas:

---

**How It Works**

Loading associative fields into a form is done by using `f.fields_for`

You'll do it like this:

```
#app/views/campaigns/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @campaign do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :items do |a| %>
        <%= a.text_field :information %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In order to get this to work, you have to `build` the associated ActiveRecord objects in the backend before you render the view, like this:

```
#app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb
def new
    @campaign = Campaign.new
    @campaign.items.build
end
```

---

**Adding Extra Fields Via Ajax**

Adding extra fields with Ajax requires engineering a new solution to the issue

The way you do this is to take the `f.fields_for` text & put it into a partial. This partial can be called from the original view, as well as another view (which we can render through Ajax)

The Ajax part works by basically taking a request from your form (the ajax request), and then using another action in your controller to build a new ActiveRecord object & render another partial that will contain another form. This partial will then call the original `f.fields_for` partial, allowing you to render another field

Your Ajax can then extract the new field & append it to your page. The way you get around the `id` issue (keeping the IDs sequential & unique) is to employ the `child_index` method, and use `Time.now.to_i` to generate a timestamp

If you read my answer referenced at the top of this answer, all of this will make sense :)

Some great resources for this:

- [RailsCasts Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Adding Fields With Ajax](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/)

Answer (score 0):

A nice gem along with tutorial is available from ryanbates who is the author of railscasts.com site.You can use [this](http://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and have a look at [tutorial here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

And also if you want to try manually use the fields_for while writing in the form like [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) and manage some jquery code for add or remove.