# Rendering partial results in syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, render, partial

Currently working on nested forms with the following railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I have an Opportunity model,

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :headings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :headings
end
```

a Heading model

```
class Heading < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opportunity
    has_many :subheadings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subheadings
end
```

and a Subheading model

```
class Subheading < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :heading
end
```

Right now I am just working on the view for the new action for the Opportunity model.

```
<h1>Add an opportunity</h1>
<%= form_for(@opportunity, :html => {:role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :headings do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'heading_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add heading", f, :headings %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the _heading_fields.html.erb partial:

```
<fieldset>
    <%= f.label :title, "Heading" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "Remove section", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add section", f, :subheadings %>
</fieldset>
```

And finally the link_to_add_fields method in the application helper:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

Now I am receiving the following error for the render call in the link_to_add_fields function:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

It seems to have something to do with the underscore in the name of the partial being rendered in the link_to_add_fields method as it goes away when the underscore is not present.

Greatly appreciate any help at solving this headache!

Comment: Can you paste full error? `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end` this type of error generally occurs when you haven't closed your loops properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Debug**

As mentioned in the comments, you're basically going to have an issue with the closing of your loops - Rails is expecting an `end` call, but you've set an identifier of sorts instead.

Having looked through your code, I cannot see where the issue might be, so I'll give you some details on how I'd debug it:

> I would remove any elements which I would presume would be causing the
>   issue, until I got it to work

For example, I would begin by replacing the `def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)` with a piece of demo content:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    "test"
end
```

If this outputs the correct string, it means the error is inside this method (which I'm guessing anyway). If this was the case, I would then try this:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = "test"
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields})
end
```

If this works, it means the problem is likely going to be with the `f.fields_for` loop which you're using. Although this is just my guess, it's basically how I'd debug - sequentially remove things until it actually works

---

**Fields**

If you're looking to add fields dynamically to your form, you may wish to use the [`cocoon` gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). The Railscast you're using is firstly a little out of date, and only allows you to add single fields to your form

The "right" way to do it is to use an ajax method, which [I detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436526/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-f-fields-for-and-ajax)

There's a very good site I found which showed you how to do it, but [the site](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/) has since gone offline. Anyway, I'll explain it for you here:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
   collection do
      get :add_field
   end
end
```

This gives you a route to send ajax requests to:

**Controller**

```
#app/views/controller/form.html.erb
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "fields", locals: { builder: f } %>
   <%= link_to "Add Field", controller_add_field_path, id: "add_field", remote: true %>
   <%= f.submit "test" %>
<% end %>

#app/views/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ActiveRecord::Base
   def add_field
      @model = Model.new
      @model.association.build
      render "add_field", layout: false
   end
end
```

**Views**

Now you need to render the `add_field` view, with the `fields_for` partial

```
#app/views/controller/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "fields", locals: { builder: f } %>
<% end %>


#app/views/controller/_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :association, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_feld :your_fields %>
<% end %>
```

**JQuery**

All you need to do then is create a way to fetch the new fields:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
$ ->
  $(document).on "ajax:success", "#add_field", (data) ->
       el_to_add = $(data).html()
       $('#new_form').append(el_to_add)
```

Comment: I have solved the problem! After lots of work I found the culprit. I had an embedded ruby comment that isn't shown here that broke the whole thing. Learned about another little trap and learned a lot in the process. Thanks so much for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice! No problem - maybe you'll want to accept to ensure people know the answer is the one which helped?

Comment: Completely forgot. Apologies. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the dynamic form fields with https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon
For some reason rBates video is outdated for rails 4.+, Cocoon was able to fix was i had spent how debugging but in Vain.
Thank you Rick Peck.