# Some more information about "indexes" added to parameters when incoming data contains array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to know some more about "indexes" added to parameters when incoming data contains array of hashes.

That is, for instance, when I run the following code (as an example, the code executes a simple AJAX request to my application)

```
var my_data = [
  { "a1": 1, "b1": 2 },
  { "a2": 1, "b2": 2 },
  { "a3": 1, "b3": 2 },
];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  "http://0.0.0.0:3000/path.json",
  data: { "my_data": my_data }
});
```

Then Rails parses the following parameters by "automagically" adding `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"` indexes:

```
{"my_data"=>{"0"=>{"a1"=>"1", "b1"=>"2"}, {"1"=>{"a2"=>"1", "b2"=>"2"}, {"2"=>{"a3"=>"1", "b3"=>"2"}}
```

1. Why Rails adds those indexes?
2. When Rails is supposed to add indexes? And when not?
3. How to avoid Rails to add indexes?

Comment: I think this is coming from having 'nested' parameters - you'll probably have to use the `child_index` option - not sure if this is exactly the same, but take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20441143/2128691)

Comment: BTW - In my case I do not use "nested" resources.

Comment: right, sorry, i didn't mean the gem, just that this is how rails deals with params that have a hierarchical structure