# How to create a child model from a parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, nested

I've been spinning may wheels with Rails on this for a few days.  I'm working with three models: `IngredientBase`, `Ingredient`, and `IngredientList`. `IngredientBase` contains a string that may be "Chicken", "Eggs", or "Bacon." Ingredient will have a single `Ingredient` and a quantity. `IngredientList` will have many Ingredients.

I want the user to be able to ingredient_lists/new and be able to create several Ingredients before submitting the `IngredientList`. How could I do this without having the user submit multiple forms?

Comment: your keyword is `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients` so you can google it and find plenty of stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Associative**

What you're looking at is [nested models](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms).

Nested models basically allow you to append attributes to an instance of one model; those attributes being sent to an associative model.

This is achieved with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
#app/models/ingredient_list.rb
class IngrendientList < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

#app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ingredient_list
end
```

---

Because your models made me confused, I rewrote the structure for you. I think you're getting confused with join models etc:

```
#app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | weight | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :recipe_ingredients
   has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

#app/models/recipe_ingredient.rb
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | recipe_id | ingredient_id | quantity | created_at | updated_at
    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end

#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :recipe_ingredients #-> allows extra attributes
   has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients 
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients
end
```

This will give you the ability to create a `Recipe`, add new `Ingredient`s, and generally keep your model much more robust.

Here's how you can make it work with controller and views etc:

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @recipe = Recipe.new
   end
   def create
      @recipe = Recipe.new recipe_params
      @recipe.save
   end

   private

   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:recipe, :params, recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:quantity, ingredient_attributes:[:name]])
   end
end
```

This will create a basic form, but we need to include the associated fields. There are several ways to do this, including the "manual" method from [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

The important thing to note is thus:

> **Every** time you call a nested form field, you're basically getting
>   Rails to add another instance of `f.fields_for` to your form. The
>   VITAL thing to note here is you need to have the ***child_index*** of the
>   `fields_for` block. This is what Rails uses to identify the fields,
>   and needs to be kept unique.

You can see more about this on [an answer I wrote some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436526/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-f-fields-for-and-ajax).

For your form, you need the following:

```
#app/views/recipes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %> 
   <%= render "ingredients", locals: {f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i}  %>
   <%= link_to "Add Ingredient", recipes_add_field_path, class: "ingredient" %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/recipes/_ingredients.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients, child_index: child_index do |ri| %>
    <%= ri.text_field :quantity %>
    <%= ri.fields_for :ingredient do |ingredient| %>
       <%= ingredient.text_field :name %>
       <%= ingredient.text_field :weight %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

#config/routes.rb
resources :recipes do
   member "add_field", to: "recipes#add_field"
end

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def add_field
      @recipe = Recipe.new
      @recipe.recipe_ingredients.build.build_ingredient
      render "new"
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a.ingredient", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/recipes/add_field',
      success: function(data){
        el_to_add = $(data).html();
        $('#recipes').append(el_to_add);
      }
      error: function(data){
         alert("Sorry, There Was An Error!");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying out this answer but I am getting an error in routes.rb why I run rake db:migrate on the line member "add_field", to: "recipes#add_field". The error I get is:

`rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
/home/reimus/mplan/config/routes.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/reimus/mplan/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/reimus/mplan/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/reimus/mplan/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle nested relations is to use `accept_nested_attributes`

For better understating here is a [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

And to manage ui level form within form here is a [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Comment: [Cocoon][https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon] is another gem - better than Ryan Bates'.