# Add one more same set of inputs on click rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-forms

How can I add one more same set of inputs for example for education object, so I will have 2 new education objects after submitting? Preferable new set needs to be shown by clicking on icon that goes after existing set of inputs.

This is my `new` method:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.educations.build
  @user.works.build
end
```

And my view for it:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |u| %>
      <%= u.error_notification %>

      <%= u.input :name, label: "Name" %>
      <p><b>Photo</b></p>
      <%= image_tag(@user.photo_url, size: "80x90",
                    class:"img-rounded") if @user.photo? %>
      <%= u.input :photo, label: false %>
      <%= u.input :tel, label: "Tel.:" %>

      <h3>Education</h3>
      <hr>
      <%= u.simple_fields_for :educations do |e| %>
        <%= e.input :name, label: "University" %>
        <%= e.input :year_started, label: "Started" %>
        <%= e.input :year_finished, label: "Ended" %>
      <% end %>

      # icon `+`
      <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>

      <h3>Work</h3>
      <hr>
      <%= u.simple_fields_for :works do |w| %>
        <%= w.input :name, label: "Name" %>
        <%= w.input :year_started, label: "Started" %>
        <%= w.input :year_finished, label: "Ended" %>
      <% end %>


      <%= u.button :submit, "Надіслати" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is probably the cocoon gem - https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to add the extra objects when you invoke the `new` method, you'd just need to "build" more associated objects:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  2.times do
    @user.educations.build
  end
  @user.works.build
end
```

This would give you two sets of `education` fields (no more code changes required).

---

If you wanted to invoke the extra objects/fields *after* you've already rendered the `new` method, you'll have to do it dynamically, through, as `@Tom Walpole` suggested, using something like [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

There is a dated, but [good tutorial here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

[I've written about it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436526/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-f-fields-for-and-ajax).

--

Adding fields on the fly relies on a simple pattern:

> 1. Button / Icon press
> 2. Ajax call to controller
> 3. Controller builds form with `fields_for`
> 4. Ajax response puts new `fields_for` in DOM

The main difference between this (ajax) and something like the "Railscast" (static) method is it builds the `fields_for` properly in rails. No hack jobs...

```
#app/views/admin/users/new.html.erb
<%= link_to fa-icon("plus 2x"), admin_new_user_path, remote: true %>
```

If you're using `font-awesome`, you'll be best with the [`font-awesome-rails`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem, as you get the [`fa-icon`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers) helper.

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html

   def new
     @user = User.new
     @user.educations.build
     @user.works.build unless request.xhr?
   end
end

#app/views/users/new.js.erb
var form = $("<%=j render 'users/new' ");
$("form#new_admin_user [[fields_for_identifier]]").html($(form).html());
```

The big trick with this is the `child_index: Time.now.to_i` method. The big problem with the "static" approach is that the `id` of each new field will be exactly the same as the last, messing up your params:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<% if request.xhr? %>
  <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |u| %>
      <%= u.simple_fields_for :educations, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |e| %>
         <%= e.input :name, label: "University" %>
         <%= e.input :year_started, label: "Started" %>
         <%= e.input :year_finished, label: "Ended" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
   ... your code ...
<% end %>
```

The above *should* work, although may need tweaking.